# VSTS rejected pull request completion workflow

Tags: azure-devops

We have VSTS pull requests (PR's) set up to require 2 reviewers before the request can complete.

This scenario happened today:

1. Pull request created with 2 reviewers
2. One reviewer accepted the PR and the other reviewer rejected
3. The author fixed and pushed up the code
4. The reviewer who had rejected the code approved
5. The PR completed successfully without the first approver seeing the update

We need the original approvals and rejections to be reset when the updated code comes in. Is this possible out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you want now exists.  (I believe it was added sometime after you posted the question.)  Under the branch policies, check the box labeled "Reset code reviewer votes when there are new changes."  [See documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#require-a-minimum-number-of-reviewers)

So far as I know this resets *all* votes, regardless of whether they were acceptances or rejections.  So in cases where an optional reviewer rejected the previous version, there's a bit of a risk that someone might then complete the pull request before that reviewer verifies that their reason for rejection was adequately addressed.

Comment: Ah, right! I forgot that I had opened this question. We've been using this functionality for many moons now, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the feature of resetting feedback (approve and reject) when code updated.

The workaround of your requirement is that you can require specific reviewers to review code.

1. Go do team project admin page (settings) > Version Control >Select a branch of a repository
2. Click Add a new path in code review requirements

[image]

After that, that user just review code of pull request after others have reviewed the code (all approve).

I submit a user voice here that you can vote. [Pull request: rest feedback of related active pull request after code changes (push new changes)](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17931436-pull-request-rest-feedback-of-related-active-pull)

Comment: That's an awesome feature that I was not aware of. However, we need to ensure that two reviewers see and review all changesets. We have security certifications that have this requirement. If we can't make that happen, then it is a hole that can block our security certification. Any other suggestions on how to get there would be appreciated.

Comment: @GaTechThomas What do you think of require specific reviewer to review code? The other way is that, reviewers can follow pull request (click ... > Follow), then reset feedback manually if receive notification (e.g other reject pull request)

Comment: @GaTechThomas I submit a user voice, you can check my answer.

Comment: Good call on the user voice. Are you able to correct the word "rest" to be "reset"? Regarding your previous question, we haven't had the opportunity to try the setting to require specific user to review the code. I don't think it would work for us... As it stands, the security compliance process that we are subject to requires two users other than the coder to review and approve all code. We don't have the ability to change that requirement. Also, would that setting behave differently from current behavior? In other words, would a new changeset clear the pull request approval?

Comment: @GaTechThomas Sorry for the mistake, but I can't modify it, because there isn't the way to modify. Regarding require specific user to review the code, it is just a workaround and can't clear the pull request approval. As far as I know, there isn't a better way for your requirement, reviewers need to clear approval manually after receiving notification.

Comment: This answer is no longer true (although no doubt it was true when it was posted two years ago).  The feature now exists.  I've posted a new answer with a link to the current documentation, plus one relevant caveat.